# Elimination of λ and μ in Lagrange method of multipliers both constraints are nonzero

Tags: partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

QUESTION: Determine maximum value of OP, O being origin of coordinates where P describes the curve $x^2 + y^2 +2z^2=5, x+2y+z=5$?

Here using lagrange method of multipliers we have two constants λ and μ ,  so taking partial derivative wrt x, y, and z we get three equations. When we try to eliminate either λ  or μ using these three equations, since both of the constraints equal to 5, we get μ in terms of λ  only.

How do we proceed from here to eliminate λ   in these type of equations with two constraints both of which equal to a non-zero constant.

The answer is $\sqrt 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An appropriate Lagrangian is

$$L(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=x^2+y^2+z^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2+2z^2-5)+\mu(x+2y+z-5).$$

The nontrivial partial derivatives are:

$$L_x = 2x+2\lambda x+\mu \\
L_y=2y+2\lambda y+2\mu \\
L_z=2z+4z\lambda+\mu.$$

If $\lambda,\mu$ were given, these conditions would allow you to find $x,y,z$: indeed $x=-\frac{\mu}{2+2\lambda},y=-\frac{2\mu}{2+2\lambda},z=-\frac{\mu}{2+4\lambda}$. One immediate consequence is that $y=2x$ (whether $\mu=0$ or not), which reduces the problem to finding the intersection of $5x^2+2z^2=5$ with $5x+z=5$. Substitution gives the quadratic equation $5x^2+2(5-5x)^2=5$. That lets you solve for $x$, obtaining two solutions. You can check whether the resulting solutions satisfy the $L_z$ condition (which we haven't used yet) and then check for optimality.

Comment: When I tried your first method it will go higher than quadratic, and problem gets more complicated. Not able to solve by that way. In your second approach "Thus you get the three equations from before and the problem reduces to finding the critical points of this function C." I didn't understand this part how the problem reduces to finding the critical points of this function C(λ,μ).  And how do you find it's critical points by taking derivatives wrt λ & μ? Can you show the calculations?

Comment: That I understood, but I'm unable to eliminate the constants. can you show the complete steps of your method and how you reached the point (1,2,0)?

Comment: @ConradTurner Frankly that is so standard that I don't think it is worthy of comment for the OP, who obviously understands the basic mechanics of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @Simple I've edited upon realizing a simpler way to proceed. I find it notable that this wouldn't work if all three axes of the ellipsoid had different lengths...

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Thank you Ian and Conrad Turner.